# Java8 - if else replacement

Tags: java-8

I have 2 variables stored in a map as `List<Object>`:

```
int value;
int[] values;
```

Here, int also will be stored as `Arrays.asList(value)`.

When we get `attributesMap.get("value")` --> It will be returned as `List<Object>`.

So, I use the following code to retrieve the value.

To get value:

```
(Integer)attributesMap.get("value").stream().findFirst().get();
```

To get values:

```
(int[])attributesMap.get("values").stream().findFirst().get();
```

Actually, only one of them will have the actual value.

The field which doesn't have an actual value will hold the default value 0, but this is not an actual value.

For example:

```
int value = 0;
int[] values = {1,2};
```

Here, values -> holding the real value and "value" can be ignored.

```
int value = 1;
int[] values = {0};
```

Here, value -> holding the real value and "values" can be ignored.

So, I need to get a final int[] array from the above two fields.

The logic I used:

```
int[] values = null;
        if (attributesMap.get("value").stream().filter(value -> ((Integer)value > 0)).count() > 0) {
            values = new int[1];
            values[0] = (Integer)attributesMap.get("value").stream().filter(value -> ((Integer)value > 0)).findFirst().get();
        }
        else if (values == null) {
            values = Arrays.stream((int[])attributesMap.get("values").stream().findFirst().get()).filter(value -> value>0).toArray();
        }
```

The other approach,

```
int[] values = attributesMap.get("value").stream().filter(value -> ((Integer)value > 0)).count() > 0
                    ? attributesMap.get("value").stream().mapToInt(val -> (int)val).toArray()
                    : (int[])attributesMap.get("values").stream().findFirst().get();
```

Is there any better approach with Java 8 without using if & else?

Comment: Just to be clear, `attributesMap.get` either returns a `List<Integer>` or a `List<int[]>`, with each list always containing a single element?

Comment: List<int[]> could return multiple values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int value = (int) attributesMap.get("value").get(0);
int[] values = value > 0 ? new int[] { value } : (int[]) attributesMap.get("values").get(0);
```

Streams are overkill for this problem, there's already a method to get the first value in a list.